# Working on the topic of continuity of a function at rational and irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that if a function f(x) on $\mathbb{R}^{1}$ is continuous at all rational numbers x, then it is continuous at some $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}- \mathbb{Q}$.

$\underline {\text{Here is my approach:}}$
Assume f(x) is continuous for all rational x. By the density of rationals, there exists a sequence of irrationals $\{x_{n}\}$ such that $x_{n} \rightarrow x.$ Since $x_{n} \in [x_{0} - |x_{0} - x_{n}|, x_{0} + |x_{0} - x_{n}|]$ and f(x) is continuous at x, then:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|f(x_{0}) - f({x_n})| \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(|x_{0} - {x_n}|) < 0$$Therefore, f(x) is continuous at $x_{0}$.
Please correct my proof it does not make sense. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos I will greatly appreciate your comment.

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to prove is false. Please consider [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). Let us call it $T$. This functions is continuous on the irrationals and only there. Now let $f(x)=T\bigl(x+\sqrt2\bigr)$. Then $f$ is continuous on the rationals, since $q\in\mathbb{Q}\implies q+\sqrt2\notin\mathbb{Q}$. But $f$ is *not* continuous everywhere. For instance, it is discontinuous at $-\sqrt2$.

Comment: This is interesting. Because when I look at this statement, I think in general for a function f (without regarding the Thomae's  function), that I will be able to come up with a proof in the context of Rudin's Analysis textbook. My assumption starts out by saying f(x) is continuous at every rational x, but Thomae's function says that f is continuous at every irrational x and discontinuous at every rational x. And the function in this statement is generally not restricted to any piece-wise condition. I am confused.

Comment: Many false statements might look like you could come up with a proof, if you did not know ahead of time that they were false. However, once you have a false statement, and a proof that it is false --- namely, a counterexample --- why would you wish to continue to try to prove that it is true?

Comment: @LeeMosher I rephrased my statement. If a function f(x) on $\mathbb{R}^{1}$ is continuous at all rational numbers x, then it is continuous at some $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}- \mathbb{Q}$. Does it make a difference?

Comment: My instructor gave me a hint that by using the fact that the set Q of all rational numbers is countable, we define osc (or oscillation) to be: $$osc(f,x_{0}) = sup(f,x_{0})-inf(f,x_{0})$$
I showed that $f$ is continuous at $x_{0}$ if and only if $\underset{[x_{0} - \epsilon,  x_{0} + \epsilon]}{osc}f \rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon$ decreases to $0$. The hint pointed me in this direction and said I can construct a sequence of closed intervals such that their intersection is equal to $x_{0}$ and osc f $\rightarrow 0$. I am not sure why the hint pointed me in such a direction.

Comment: @Hugh The only way I know of proving the statment “If a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at the rationals, then it is continuous at *some* irrational” uses this idea. But it requires the use of the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

This is false i am afraid. You need to prove that for any sequence converging to the point you have that the limit definition of continuity is satisfied. See this for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function

Continuity on a dense set does not imply anything

Comment: I am not quite clear about your statement above.

Comment: Why don't you take a look to the topological definition of continuity? For ANY sequence the limit must be equal to the value of the function on $x_0$. Indeed, as you can find out in the example above, even continuity on a dense open set does not imply the function is continuous. You are taking limits on rationals, which is neglecting points where things are not going that well

Comment: Why should I explore this topic in terms of the topology topic?

Comment: Because it should make your ideas more clear. Take for istance the function which is $1$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ otherwise. You cannot cherrypick your test sequences, as it is made very clear by the topological (aka $\epsilon$-$\delta$) definition.

Comment: How can I approach this statement using real analysis concept?

Comment: As I tried to expain you, the statement is false. I gave you 2 counterexamples to your claim (the last comment for the basic one).